# Unable to populate lsitbox in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to populate a list box from a customers table in SQL database.I tested with WPF list box the code is working good but when i try to implement in asp.net web application i am unable to populate the list box. Here is my code

```
 try
            {
                string query = "SELECT customer_ID FROM Customers WHERE ID = 1";
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query , conn);
                da.Fill(ds);
                foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    listbox1.SelectedValue = row["customer_ID"].ToString();
                    samplelist.Add(listbox1.SelectedValue);

                }

                listbox1.DataSource = samplelist;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
```

Can any one guide me in the right direction ?

Comment: You set `SelectedValue` in an empty listbox and then add the `SelectedValue` to a list that becomes the listbox's datasource. What time is it where you live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {

                samplelist.Add(row["WORKSTATION_ID"].ToString());

            }

            listbox1.DataSource = samplelist;
    listbox1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the below code:

```
        try
        { 
            string query = "SELECT customer_ID FROM Customers WHERE ID = 1"; 
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()); 
            conn.Open(); 
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn); 
            da.Fill(ds);

            listbox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            listbox1.DataTextField = "WORKSTATION_ID";
            listbox1.DataValueField = "WORKSTATION_ID";
            listbox1.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception) 
        { 
        }
```

Comment: all three above suggestions are working..can't i mark all as answers

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to trim this down somewhat to the following. You're missing the DataBind() as well.:

```
try
{
//Existing to fill ds, check table exists, etc.
listbox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
listbox1.DataValueField = "COLUMNNAME";
listbox1.DataTextField = "COLUMNNAME";
listbox1.DataBind();
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```